# Photon crashing on pubnum publish (red light flashing)

Tags: pubnub, photon

I have a program that compiles and flashes to the Photon without problem. It runs well until it publishes a string to PubNub. By changing the string being sent, I get different results.

The following examples are relevant:

This works:

```
    String msg = String(tempc);
    client = PubNub.publish(channel, msg);
```

This works:

```
    String msg = String("24");
    client = PubNub.publish(channel, msg);
```

This causes the photon to crash (flash red):

```
    msg = "24.000:145:654"
    client = PubNub.publish(channel, msg);
```

Can you advise why the introduction of delimiters (=,-,:) causes the photon to crash.

Many thanks.

Comment: You probably need to urlencode the msg. Which PubNub SDK/version are you using?

Comment: I am using the SDK as pulled in by BUILD. I am not sure how to tell from the library code what version it is. The app was built 2 days ago, so it is using the current web based library version.

Comment: Can you send your code to [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support)? Reference this SO link in your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, but i'm not sure why the previous "msg" construct did not work (If anyone can shed light on this for me, I would greatly appreciate it).

Here is the msg construct that i used to solve the problem. It is now in an object form and quite easy to work with on the Javascript side.

```
        char msgChar[150] = "";

    String tempstring = "{\"tN\":\"" + oT.f2s(oT.Now()) + "\",\
\"tH\":\"" + oT.f2s(oT.Low()) + "\",\
\"tL\":\"" + oT.f2s(oT.High()) + "\",\
\"hN\":\"" + oH.f2s(oH.Now()) + "\",\
\"hH\":\"" + oH.f2s(oH.Low()) + "\",\
\"hL\":\"" + oH.f2s(oH.High()) + "\",\
\"lN\":\"" + oL.f2s(oL.Now()) + "\",\
\"lH\":\"" + oL.f2s(oL.Low()) + "\",\
\"lL\":\"" + oL.f2s(oL.High()) + "\"}";

    tempstring.toCharArray (msgChar, 150);
```

Thank you to those of you who contributed to the solution.